# How to use global variable so i can use it on my javascript module

Tags: javascript, html, variables, iife

i want to get all of this input values to my budget app
but i have problem to get values of the radio button because it says its undefined. i create global function to get by radio button value. but the others  is in javascript module.

https://jsfiddle.net/8k3gw7ty/

```
<div class="button_income">
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="inc" id="incomebtn" onclick="getButtonValue();" checked>
  <label for="incomebtn" class="income-btn">+ Add Income</label>
</div>
<div class="button_expense">
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="exp" id="expensebtn" onclick="getButtonValue();">
  <label for="expensebtn" class="expense-btn">+ Add Expense</label>
</div>
<div class="desc_input">
  <label class="labelinput" for="input-desc">Your Income/Expense Description</label>
  <input id="input-desc" type="text" class="input_description" placeholder="Salary">
</div>
<div class="value_input">
  <label class="labelinput" for="input-val">Value of Income/Expense</label>
  <input id="input-val" type="number" class="input_value" placeholder="Rp. 100.000">
</div>
```

Comment: what is budgetController here?

Comment: still empty, but it has nothing do to with button value

Comment: Radiobuttons and checkboxes only have a value when the are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no default value for your `val` variable. Since `val` will only get value when you click on the checkbox (according to your code).

Also you were returning `val` which isn't necessary. I've also removed the `budgetController`.

Hope this'll help.

```js
let val = 'inc'; // default value
function getButtonValue() {
  var type = document.getElementsByName("type");
  if (type[0].checked) {
    val = type[0].value
  } else if (type[1].checked) {
    val = type[1].value
  }
}

const domController = (function() {

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        type: val,
        description: document.querySelector(".input_description").value || 0,
        value: parseFloat(document.querySelector(".input_value").value) || 0
      }


    }


  }

})();

const controller = (function( UI) {

  var ctrlAddItem = function() {
    var input = UI.getInput();
    console.log(input);

  }

  document.querySelector(".addbtn").addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem)

  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }
  });


})( domController);
```

```html
<div class="button_income">
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="inc" id="incomebtn" onclick="getButtonValue();" checked>
  <label for="incomebtn" class="income-btn">+ Add Income</label>
</div>
<div class="button_expense">
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="exp" id="expensebtn" onclick="getButtonValue();">
  <label for="expensebtn" class="expense-btn">+ Add Expense</label>
</div>
<div class="desc_input">
  <label class="labelinput" for="input-desc">Your Income/Expense Description</label>
  <input id="input-desc" type="text" class="input_description" placeholder="Salary">
</div>
<div class="value_input">
  <label class="labelinput" for="input-val">Value of Income/Expense</label>
  <input id="input-val" type="number" class="input_value" placeholder="Rp. 100.000">
</div>
<button><i class="fas fa-check addbtn">Save</i></button>
```

Comment: it works with the default value. but when i check expense button the type is still inc

Comment: I've just check this and found it's working fine here. Would you please check this screencast [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/117fe4af7ae7c2d22adfc1b59f7f01e520200418161651/86b10e)

Comment: You are always welcome. if my answer solves your issue then please mark this answer as accepted.  This will help others as well @NurulHudaSultonAulia